# Click function on appended link does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On clicking a link, I want to display a div and append another link in that div. Then I want to use click function on the appended link.

In my code below the click function on the link 'click' does not work. I am unable to figure out the problem. I will appreciate any help.

Please check the JsFiddle to see the problem.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QYL3x/

**jQuery:**

```
$('.big-link').click(function(e){
    $('#myDiv').append('<a class="link" href="#">Click</a>');
});


$('.link').click(function(e){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myDiv">Fade</a>
<div id="myDiv" class="reveal-modal"></div>
```

Comment: use $('.link').live('click',function(){}) OR $('.link').on('click',function(){});  [YourFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYL3x/11/)

Comment: The `.click()` event binding was already executed when the JavaScript file was parsed and run by the browser. It didn't find your `.link` element because it didn't exist yet. You need to change the way in which the `.link` element binding works - see [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @AliExalter [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: and [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/218196)

Comment: @andyb I know But he is using 1.8.3 in fiddle. For 1.9 use .on() here is link to 1.9 example [jSFiddle1.9](http://jsfiddle.net/QYL3x/12/)

Comment: @AliExalter Fine. `.live` was _deprecated_ in 1.7. `.on` was introduced in 1.7. `.on` is the correct function to recommend from 1.7 onwards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a delegated event handler. This is because your current code is trying to attach an event to `.link` before it exists in the DOM.

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', '.link', function(e){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/QYL3x/4/)

Answer (score 3):

use [.on](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/QYL3x/10/)

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

```
$("#myDiv").on('click','.link',function(e){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/QYL3x/10/)**

Comment: wrong syntax and wrong selector ...

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.click` function is binded to the **elements** that are **present in the DOM**. You need to add a **delegate event listener**:

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', '.link', function(e){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rory's solution is perfect. Also, there is one more variant which I use generally, that don't need delegation.  This is binding the event when you create the element.

```
$('.big-link').click(function(e){
    $('#myDiv').append(
       $('<a/>' { 
           'class' : 'link' ,
           'href'  : '#' , 
           'click' : function(){ alert  ( 'hi' ); }
       } )
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/QYL3x/1/

```
$('#myDiv').on('click','.link',function(e){
     alert("clicked");
});
```

just add delegation

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#myDiv').on('click', '.link', function(e){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/QYL3x/2/

```
$('.big-link').click(function(e){
    var link = $('<a class="link" href="#">Click</a>');
    link.click(function(e){
        alert("clicked");
    });
    $('#myDiv').append(link);
});
```